# Vrep to generate trajectory

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic, ur10, vrep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, i'm new in ros and i'm trying to move my simulated UR10 in gazebo. What i'm doing is setting up the same scene in Vrep  (now CoppeliaSim), where also i generate a set of points of my target trajectory, composed by 6*300=1800 points(each joint has 300 points to follow).
I also have a jointTrajectoryController and the related actions. Is there a way to move my simulated robot using this points? I suppose Vrep has to publish some message to the /follow_joint_trajectory/goal topic but i have some problem understanding how to compose the message to publish. Tell me if i'm wrong, but i suppose i can't just copy and paste this 1800 points in the "Points" field of the action message.
I also tried something really terrible using 6 differents JointPositionController, one for each joint, and sending them alternately the point to reach through the /command topic, something like this pseudocode:

```
for i=1,1800,1 do
    publish(controller[i%6 +1],points[i])
end
```

I can't use only the last point, i want to follow the exact same trajectory vrep generated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343731/vrep-to-generate-trajectory/) by [BlueSkeptical](https://answers.ros.org/users/51641/blueskeptical/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2020-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I suppose Vrep has to publish some message to the `/follow_joint_trajectory/goal` topic but i have some problem understanding how to compose the message to publish.

Provided you are using `ur_gazebo` (or a similar package) which exposes a `FollowJointTrajectory` action server, you'd have to write something that instantiates and populates a [control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectory](http://docs.ros.org/api/control_msgs/html/action/FollowJointTrajectory.html) goal and then submits it to the action server.

The goal is not that difficult to create. Something like this would do it:

```
from control_msgs.msg import FollowJointTrajectoryAction, FollowJointTrajectoryGoal
from trajectory_msgs.msg import JointTrajectory, JointTrajectoryPoint

...

# using the action namespace you mentioned in your question here
client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('follow_joint_trajectory', FollowJointTrajectoryAction)
client.wait_for_server()

goal = FollowJointTrajectoryGoal()
goal.trajectory = JointTrajectory()

# NOTE: order matters here! This HAS to correspond to how the
#       values in your VREP trajectory are ordered
goal.trajectory.joint_names = [
  'shoulder_pan_joint',
  'shoulder_lift_joint',
  'elbow_joint',
  'wrist_1_joint',
  'wrist_2_joint',
  'wrist_3_joint'
]

# not entirely sure how your 'points' list (array?) is built up. I'm
# assuming a list of tuple(float, float, float, float, float, float)
# here. Adjust as necessary.

for p in points:
  goal.trajectory.points.append(
    JointTrajectoryPoint(
      positions=list(p),
      velocities=...,
      accelerations=...,
      effort=...,
      time_from_start=rospy.Duration(...)))

# finally: submit the goal for execution
client.send_goal(goal)

# optional
client.wait_for_result()
```

You'll want to make sure to specify proper velocities, as I expect the controller to stop at each point in your trajectory if you don't.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1